# Setting tintColor on UIImageView produces unexpected color output

Tags: ios, uikit, tintcolor

[image: TintColor on iPhone X]
[image: TintColor on iPhone SE]

I have a `UIImageView` with the `tintColor` property set to `.red`. Also the `backgroundColor` of the `UIImageView` is set to `.red`

The image itself is a pdf file which is set to render as template in my assets catalogue.

The upper image is the output on an iPhone X and the image below is shot on an iPhone SE.

My question now is: What is iOS doing when tinting images? Why is there such a huge difference between the two devices? And why are the images always darker than the color I set them to?

I expected when I set the `tintColor` property of a `UIImageView` that the image is displayed in the exact same color.

UPDATE:

I added a test project with a sketch file and the exported pdf to reproduce the issue:

https://github.com/NickAtGit/TintTest

Comment: I'd make sure my pdf's color space is RGB and the black is 000 with 100% opacity.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with my assets. There is something wrong with your Pdf file.

Comment: @Desdenova I added a test project with a sketch file

Comment: Yes I just checked it. Your pdf seems alright. Still can't reproduce your bug with simulator. That would be a shame if this is an oled issue.

Comment: Yeah, there is the problem. You have to test it on real devices... @Desdenova

Comment: The issue didn't occur when I tried to produce it on simulators nor on real devices. Can you share the real image so i try to test on it

Comment: The issue didn't occur when I tried to produce it on simulators nor on real devices. Can you share the real image so i try to test on it

Comment: @JhonnyTawk the pdf image is in the linked Github project. You have to try it on a real device, not on a simulator!

Comment: @nico-s I tried on real device and simulator both are the same. can you re-check the tint-Color and backgroundColor for the image.

Comment: Which device do you have @JhonnyTawk ?

Comment: I tested on iPhone XS & iPhone 5s

Comment: As you can see in the project both background and tintColor are red @JhonnyTawk

Comment: what Xcode version are you using? maybe that's the problem but I doubt it

Comment: both have the same iOS version?

Answer (score 0):

The tint property is multiplying the normalized(0-1) color of each pixel in the image by Red(1,0,0). Resulting in the image only having the Red channel tint applied(blue and green are both zero). In the SE image, the tint on the blue and green channels are not honored/applied(since they are zero), resulting in nonstandard behavior, when compared to other "tinting" schemes, see XNA Draw() Color parameter, which appears to be corrected in the iOS for iPhone X.
To use the darker image set the `TintAdjustmentMode` property to `TintAdjustmentMode.dimmed`, otherwise use  `TintAdjustmentMode.normal`

Comment: Ok, and how can I get correctly tinted images then?

Comment: That depends, which image do you consider correct, the top or bottom?

Comment: I want the top one to be completely red